# updating the user location in the background swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

I'm working on an app and I need to notify the user when he leaves the place that he is in
so I was able to get the user's current location but I couldn't use the location in the background
after some search I found that I can update the location when the user move !
so is it really possible !? and how can I do it ?!

Comment: You'll want to read up on `CLLocationManager`. http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at GeoFencing try this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

it will help.Thank you